# Powershell 7.3 - Install Missing Module if #requires fails

Tags: powershell

I have a script that requires a specific module in order to run. The #Requires functionality works to stop the script from continuing, however, I would like the script to install the module should it not exist.

Added #Requires to the script. Now I need it to install the missing module rather than stop the script from running

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply test the presence for the module :

```
if (-not (Get-Module -Name MyNeededModule -ListAvailable))
{
   Install-Module -Name MyNeededModule [-Scope CurrentUser|AllUsers]
}
```

When you use the `Get-Module` cmdlet, you will get only the loaded modules, adding the `-ListAvailable` will list all the module installed even if they are not loaded.

Default scope is `CurrentUser`, if you choose `AllUsers` you need administrative rights.